# Parsing images with Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm working with Jsoup, in Android, I want to obtain the attribute "src" from the first tag "img" from this web: http://www.proyectoglass.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss, for some reason that I can't figure the program is stopping, and I'm clueless. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView test=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.testText);

    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.proyectoglass.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss").ignoreContentType(true).get(); 
        Element img =  doc.select("img").first();
        test.setText(""+img.attr("abs:src"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        test.setText(e.toString());
    }

}
```

This my LogCat:

```
06-14 15:57:48.064: W/dalvikvm(542): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jsoup_test/com.example.jsoup_test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at com.example.jsoup_test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-14 15:57:48.106: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  ... 11 more
```

In the web, I want to obtain the url from src.

```
<img width="640" height="344" border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-tNEIyl1tTJA/UbRVa2bKpiI/AAAAAAAAAs4/xqW9VPw7b9g/s640/Larry-Page-Google-Project-Glass.jpg"/>
```

Comment: which tag do you want to parse can you post the same?

Comment: I'm trying to parse the attribute "src" from the "img" tag, so basically I want to get the address of the first image in the web that I'm connecting with.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

You are doing a bad thing of calling method on an object reference that refers to nothing (null) on line 28 in your MainActivity.java.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it, and I will remember it in the future. Any other advice? I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @user1012024 What have you changed? I suggest improving your question by putting info, which line is 28 in your code and if it's `test.setText(e.toString());`, what's the real exception.

Comment: @user1012024 u should probably use asynctask also. and also post which tag you want to parse coz if you open this http://www.proyectoglass.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss  in browser we can't figure out which tag you want to parse

Comment: @Raghunandan Sorry, I edited the question trying to be more clear, please let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: @user1012024 looks like a xml document. open this link and check. looks like rss feed

Comment: @user1012024 assuming you have the tags as mentioned in the question  you can check my answer

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes, is a XML with Rss feed but I though Jsoup was able to parse also XML, It has some HTML code embedded on it and there is where the img tag is.

Comment: @user1012024 then you don't have tag as mentioned in the link. if its xml you should use a xml parser

Comment: @Raghunandan I think the problem is that in that XML the img tag is formated like &lt;img&gt; for instance of <img> so jsoup is not able to find it as tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are link looks like rss feed (http://www.proyectoglass.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss).

Any way assuming you have the html as and using asynctask

```
<img width="640" height="344" border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-tNEIyl1tTJA/UbRVa2bKpiI/AAAAAAAAAs4/xqW9VPw7b9g/s640/Larry-Page-Google-Project-Glass.jpg"/>
```

You can do as below

```
String html ="<img width="+640+" height="+344+" border="+0+" src="+"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-tNEIyl1tTJA/UbRVa2bKpiI/AAAAAAAAAs4/xqW9VPw7b9g/s640/Larry-Page-Google-Project-Glass.jpg"+"/>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("img").first();
String s = link.attr("src");
```

Edit:

```
public class asynctask extends Activity {

TextView tv;
ArrayList<String> bb = new ArrayList<String>();
ProgressDialog pd;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
pd = new ProgressDialog(asynctask.this);
pd.setMessage("Loading..");
new TheTask().execute(); 
} 
class TheTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>
{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd.show();
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try
    {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.proyectoglass.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss");

    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
    xpp.setInput(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), "UTF_8"); 
    //xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF-8");   
    boolean insideItem = false;
    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

            if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                insideItem = true;
            } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                if (insideItem)
                {

                }       
            } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                if (insideItem)
                {

                }
            }
            else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                if (insideItem)
                    bb.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
            }
        }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
            insideItem=false;
        }

        eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
    }


} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPostExecute(result);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(bb.get(0).toString());
Element link = doc.select("img").first();
String s = link.attr("src"); 
pd.dismiss();
tv.setText(s);
}
}   
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
     >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Snap Shot

[image]

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well, sorry. I just showed that tag to show the one that I'm trying to parse, but I need to parse from the website. I know that is a RSS feed but I need to create a app to show the feeds on that website (I allready have the text and now I'm getting the images) and since the website is build with scripts is not possible to do so with the main website (www.proyectoglass.com), thanks!

Comment: @user1012024 you have to parse you rss feed get the description content and then get the url from it

Comment: @user1012024 i just parsed the rss fedd and will post the solution in the edit

Comment: @user1012024 check the edited answer and the snap shot attached. i assume this is what you are looking for

Comment: @user1012024 did u try the above. also check this documentation http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html. let me know if the above works

Comment: Thanks! Yes it works. The problem is that if I do it in XML parser I have to change the main app (this was just a test that I was doing to see if isolating the problem I was able to figure out why was happening), anyway I guess is better if I work with this parser, I allready had some other troubles parsing with jsoup and this website :P.

Comment: @user1012024 you comment is not clear to me. to the question you posted i have answered and if it helps pls accept the same.  i took much time in figuring out your problem and then finally provided the solution

Comment: @user1012024 integrating this in your main app should not be a problem. so what is the other problem you are facing. You can post the same as a new question.